# Entity framework creating new entries from navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following models:

```
public class Conversation
{
    public int ConversationId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}


public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
}
```

And Im hitting the following endpoint:

```
        private DirectAPIContext db = new DirectAPIContext();

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Conversation> CreateConversation([FromBody] Conversation conversation)
    {
        Conversation newConversation = conversation;

        db.Conversations.Add(newConversation);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return newConversation;
    }
```

With this data:

```
 {
"ConversationId": 7,
  "Owner": {
    "UserId": 27,
    "Name": null,
    "Conversations": null
  },
  "Users": [
    {
      "UserId": 28,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    },
    {
      "UserId": 29,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    },
    {
      "UserId": 30,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of referencing the preexisting user objects Entity Framework is creating new users objects like so:

```
    {
  "ConversationId": 7,
  "Owner": {
    "UserId": 27,
    "Name": null,
    "Conversations": null
  },
  "Users": [
    {
      "UserId": 28,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    },
    {
      "UserId": 29,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    },
    {
      "UserId": 30,
      "Name": null,
      "Conversations": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Im not sure if I am doing navigation properties incorrectly. The relationship between Conversation and User should be many to many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is expected behavior. EF will attempt to insert any object which you have added (either directly or via a navigation property) UNLESS that object is already attached to the tracking graph. In that case it will instead add a relevant FK or link table row.

What you want to do is call `db.Users.Attach(user)` on each of the users which you know are already in the database. This should give you the expected behavior (eg adding a link row instead of inserting a new user row)